# Django model field dynamic choices which calls API

Tags: django

Say I have the following model:

```py
class DenyList(models.Model):
    vm_id = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

I want to add choices to the `vm_id` field, however the choices are dynamic via API of an external virtual machine registry system.

so I have that done in the following way:

```py
class MachineChoices(object):

    def get_vms(self):
        if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv:
            return []
        # calls api, optionally cache, return the vms

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.get_vms()


class DenyList(models.Model):
    vm_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=MachineChoices())
```

The above works that:

1. When creating migrations it won't call the API to set all the options in the migration file
2. It is driven from the backend so it works on all model forms so as in django admin.
3. Django admin displays the label instead of the raw value in list display (requires caching implemented in `MachineChoices` for efficiency)

I don't feel this is elegant as it involves hackery to deceive django especially during migrations.

I am aware that an alternative is to use autocomplete libraries but I need to customize with django forms.

So are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: you can use form's `__init__` method to initialize choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `choices` to `None` (or empty list) in your `AppConfig` instead.

myapp/apps.py:

```py
import sys

from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv:
            from . import models
            models.Company.street_num.field.choices = None
```

If you don't want to configure each model field specifically:

```py
if 'makemigrations' in sys.argv or 'migrate' in sys.argv:
    for model in self.models.values():
        for field in model._meta.fields:
            field.choices = None
```

---

Remember to include your `AppConfig` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

mysite/settings.py:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
]
```